# Login on public Wi-Fi networks using HTTPS

Tags: tls, passwords, email, wifi

Is it safe to log in to my e-mail account with my iPad's Safari through a public Wi-Fi network (let's suppose someone is eavesdropping the traffic) provided that the e-mail provider uses HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection to the email provider is SSL encrypted (starting from your iPad, not the public access point), so this can be considered safe.

Comment: Can the owner of the wi-fi network or somebody else (the same hacker eavesdropping on the traffic) spoof the SSL certificate?

Comment: A man-in-the-middle attack is theoretically possible with a forged certificate but your email program would warn you before connecting and transmitting any data. The same goes for web requests over https.